# error factory not registered after switching to factory bot

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I have factory bot in spec_helper.rb

```
config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
```

So I updated the factory from FactoryGirl to FactoryBot as follows

spec/factories/products.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :products do
    id Faker::Number.between(100, 900)
    ...more fields...
  end
end
```

and trying to use it in request spec as follows

spec/request/products_request_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Products Request', type: :request do
  let(:products) { FactoryBot.create(:products) }
  let(:base_path) { '/products' }
 .....something here...
end
```

When i try to run test i get `factory not registerd: products`. What is it i am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think it fixes anything but should `spec/factories/events.rb` be `spec/factories/products.rb`?

Comment: Do you use spring? If so - try `spring stop` and see if the problems persist.

Comment: I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

Okay I figured it out. The documentation isn't super clear, but when working with rails you don't use the `factory_bot` gem but instead you use the `factory_bot_rails` gem.

Problem solved.